# Roles/Permissions Based Authorization Gem with Roles & Permissions in the Database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have been working with Ruby/Rails for years. The community is great. You can find a gem for pretty much anything you want to do.

Having said that, is there a reason why there is no gem which can do **Roles and Permissions Based Authorization where Roles and Permissions are stored in the Database** right out of the box?

*In my experience, this is a basic requirement for pretty much any web application that is more than just a static website.* (obviously an arguable statement!)

I know there are tons of options out there for authorization like [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit), [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) etc etc. But none of them do all of what I mentioned above.

I am not looking for code examples on how to accomplish this. I am looking for a `gem` that can do it all and use database to store roles and permissions. Is there one?

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [TheRole](https://github.com/the-teacher/the_role). Seems like it has ability to store permissions in DB as you want.

+ UI for manage roles [here](https://github.com/TheRole/the_role_management_panel).

Comment: It does look decent. I'll try it out and report back on how good and complete it is.

Comment: @San you were supposed to report back :D

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal You are correct. My apologies. In fact I ended up rolling my own solution. None of the gems that I found, including this one did exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @San you should than post your solution and make that accepted answer, this is the best way to go i think. Will help all beginners like me.

Comment: @San you never posted what you did.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumble upon this question - there are 2 more gems I found out: [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) and [Royce](https://github.com/MartinJNash/Royce). I think that first one can be used smoothly with Pundit and CanCanCan.